# Reset QueryProperty value on load - MVVM

Tags: mvvm, maui

Okay so I have an app that starts out with a Login screen. After logging in, it passes a Dictionary object to my main page that is used to select a starter Picker value. My app also contains a flyout menu for navigation.

My issue is that if I choose a value in the Picker that isn't the default value passed in the Dictionary from login, navigate to any page from the main screen, then navigate back, it resets my picker value to what's in the dictionary instead of what I just picked. I'm not super familiar with the QueryProperty, but I believe my solution involves just updating the QueryProperty to the new selected value and I don't know how to do that.

LoginViewModel:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///" + nameof(Main), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   {"SelectedOrderGuideIndex", selectedOrderGuideIndex }
});
```

MainViewModel:

```cs
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
   [QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedOrderGuideIndex), "SelectedOrderGuideIndex")]
   public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
   {
      [ObservableProperty]
      int selectedOrderGuideIndex = -1;

      // emitted non-important code
      
      async partial void OnSelectedOrderGuideIndexChanged(int value) {
         await LoadSelection(value);
      }

      async void LoadSelection(int value) {
         // do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Main.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Main"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models.Enums"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:MainViewModel"
             Title="Items">
   <VerticalStackLayout>
      <Border Stroke="Black" Background="White" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="10,0,10,0">
         <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
         </Border.StrokeShape>
         <Picker TextColor="Black" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished" x:Name="CustomerPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderGuideHeaders}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrderGuideIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Select" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CustomerName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
      </Border>
      <!-- Other stuff -->
   </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

AppShell.xaml (Flouyout):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell>
   <Shell.FlyoutContent>
      <VerticalStackLayout>
         <Button Text="Settings" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="White" Clicked="{Binding GoToSettingsCommand}" />
         <Button Text="Custom Sequence" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="White" Clicked="{Binding GoToCustomSequenceCommand}" />
      </VerticalStackLayout>
   </Shell.FlyoutContent>
</Shell>
```

Code for navigation:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToSettings()
{
   await Current.GoToAsync("Settings");
}

[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToCustomSequence()
{
   await Current.GoToAsync("CustomSequence");
}
```

So when you navigate, it just slides out the page that you attempt to navigate to (settings, custom sequence, etc.) and then to get back, it has the back arrow. I've put some breakpoints down and tried different initial selections for the picker and it always resets to the default value of the Picker that comes from LoginViewModel when you click on the back arrow from any page. I was wondering if I could update the value in that dictionary that's initially passed in the OnSelectOrderGuideIndexChanged method such that it would "update" it to what I set it to after logging in.

Comment: Workarounds can be found in the [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10294). One workaround is to clear nav dictionary. Then it does nothing when page is refreshed.